# why doesnt my actionListener work with my jcomboBox

Tags: java, swing

I know I'm missing something very simplem but for the life of me I can't see it. All I want to do is get "Paris" from the combo box, and when the button is pressed, show that "Paris" is selected.

```
public class assignment2try2 implements ActionListener {
    private JComboBox HolidayLocation;  
    private JComboBox HolidayDuration;
    private JButton PriceCheck; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        JLabel Location = new JLabel(" Where do you want to go ? ");

        String[] HolidayLocations = {" ","Paris", "Crete", "Croatia"};
        JComboBox<String> LocationBox = new JComboBox<String>(HolidayLocations);
        LocationBox.setEditable(false);
        LocationBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension( 160, 20 ));
        //LocationBox.setSelectedIndex(4);
        LocationBox.addActionListener(LocationBox);

        JButton PriceCheck = new JButton("Check Availability");
        PriceCheck.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("button works");
                //if(LocationBox.getSelectedItem().equals(HolidayLocations))
                {
                    //System.out.println("paris selected");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking if `LocationBox.getSelectedItem().equals(HolidayLocations)`? You are checking if the selected item matches the *whole* array.

Comment: what should i do for its just to pull Paris from the comboBox ?

Comment: You should pull the selected item and display it.

Comment: how would i achive this ?

Comment: I'll try to come up with an answer in a second.

Comment: `what should i do for its just to pull Paris from the comboBox ?` read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html). It has a working example on how to use an ActionListener. Also, follow Java naming conventions. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. The tutorial also shows a better way to structure your code. `LocationBox.addActionListener(LocationBox);` - not sure what that code is for. You don't add the combo box as an ActionListener.

Comment: `"Paris".equals(locationBox.getSelectedItem())`??

Comment: But why would you check what the input is, instead of displaying it regardless of what the selected item is?

Comment: i tried your way mad programmer and it asked me to make my variable locationBox to a final String

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I just now noticed that your class `implements ActionListener`. With the below solution, you can remove the `implements`-statement from *your* code.

To fix your issues with the String having to be final, make a private class:

```
private class MyListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println(locationBox.getSelectedItem() + " selected.");
    }
}
```

Then, replace

```
PriceCheck.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { ... });
```

with

```
PriceCheck.addActionListener(new MyListener());
```

This should be able to print out the selected value after the button is pressed.

Note: I changed your variable name from `LocationBox` to `locationBox` to comply with naming conventions.

Comment: it keeps telling me that my location Box needs to be a final String

Comment: thanks martin i will try and implement it and see how it goes

Comment: @UpAllNight123 I've further updated my answer, to explain how you now would add MyListener to the button.

Comment: @UpAllNight123. So have you read the tutorial link that I provide you with yet??? It shows you how to better structure your program so you don't have these problems. Learn from working examples!!!

Comment: @UpAllNight123 How did it go?

Comment: not very well :/ it still wouldnt find the data in the combo box and when it did run it wouldnt even show all the possibilities in the combo box

Comment: You cannot access the combo box from outside the main method. Make it a private member, and try again.